# How to link to the same workspace?

Tags: perforce

I have two computers: Work, and Home.

My workspace in my Work Laptop is synced in a Dropbox. That's why I could access my work at home.

But when I try to setup my Perforce at home, I don't know how to link or detect that I have an existing workspace in my Dropbox.

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'll assume you can access your Perforce server from home, since you don't mention this in your problem statement.

Next, I'll assume you're able to use the same directory structure at home that you use at work (e.g. C:\Dropbox\projx).

When you create your client spec at work, be sure to edit out the HOST: line, since you'll be using it on two machines.

Use the same client name at home that you use at work.

If for some reason you are unable to use the same directory structure on both machines, you may have to use "p4 client" to change the ROOT: line of your client spec every time you switch between home and work.

Alternatively, you could use two different clients, and use "p4 shelve" to move files to the server when you're done for the day.

Comment: You don't need to keep changing the client root; that's what `AltRoots` is for.

Answer (score 3):

You basically just need to tell Perforce the name of your client.  Usually you'll do this by adding a `.p4config` file in your Perforce client's root directory (or in one of its parent directories) that contains the line:

```
P4CLIENT=your-perforce-client-name
```

You might also need to add an environment variable that points to this file: `P4CONFIG=.p4config`.

If the local path to your client's root is different between your work and home machines, you'll also need to set `AltRoots` in your Perforce client specification and add the path for your home machine.